# App rejected: Systematic way to find (cocoapod) library that accesses privacy-sensitive data

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, info.plist

iTunes Connect just told me that

> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
>   description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data.

My app however doesn't make use of the microphone. How can I *systematically* find out which of my (cocoapods) dependencies are responsible for that?

There are >20 dependencies and I'd like to avoid manually removing dependencies (and uncommenting my code using it) just to find which one of them causes the rejection since build time + submitting + "waiting for processing" takes a lot of time.

Comment: Can you list the pods you're using? Have you tried searching for references/imports of AVFoundation/AVAudioSession?

Comment: This question is whether there's an _automatic_ approach to detect which cocoapod library requires the microphone. By doing bisect on all dependencies I've now found out which library is responsible (google-cast-sdk) but it took more than 1 hour and I'd like to avoid it in the future.

Comment: @Gereon Google-Cast-SDK is closed source, it only provides a compiled binary. Can I still find out which imports it's doing?

Comment: Yes, indirectly by looking at the symbol tables of the shared library. In your case, `nm Pods/google-cast-sdk/GoogleCastSDK-Public-3.2.0-Release/GoogleCast.framework/GoogleCast` will show a reference to AVAudioSession

Comment: Works like a charm. If you post this as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For closed-source Pods, use `nm` to show the symbol tables of the shared libraries. In this case, the command would be `nm Pods/google-cast-sdk/GoogleCastSDK-Public-3.2.0-Release/Goog‌​leCast.framework/Goo‌​gleCast`, which lists a reference to `AVAudioSession`.

Answer (score -3):

In your app's plist, add "NSMicrophoneUsageDescription" and add description for that.

Comment: That wasn't the question